# Julia - How to properly concatenate with non-defined variable

Tags: variables, julia, concatenation

I want to write a loop that creates a plot and concatenates each of them. But the problem is,
the variable is initially non-existent, so the concatenation doesn't work. Here is an
example:

```
for i = 1:10
 myplot = hcat(myplot,plot(x[i],y[i]))
end
```

Now, I can solve this problem by doing the first iteration separately. But I was wondering if there is a more "elegant" way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use comprehension:

```
myplots = [plot(x[i],y[i]) for i = 1:10]
```

Note that if you want to rather overlay plots try the `plot!` function. If you want just to plot points there is a `scatter` function.

Comment: Thanks! The plots was more of an example, I'm actually using VegaLite. Cheers!